# Looping through XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

My XML file structure looks like this:

```
<SalaryDetails>
    <Employee>
        <Name>George Dsouza</Name>
        <AnnualSalary>320000</AnnualSalary>
        <DaysWorked>22</DaysWorked>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Jackie Parera</Name>
        <AnnualSalary>300000</AnnualSalary>
        <DaysWorked>19</DaysWorked>
    </Employee>
...
</SalaryDetails>
```

I want to put all the data into database as employe records using `XmlDocument`.

So I wrote a loop like this:

```
XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

xdcDocument.Load(@"D:\SalaryDetails.xml");

XmlElement xelRoot = xdcDocument.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/SalaryDetails/Employee");

foreach(XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
    {
        //What to write here??
        //My sql insert command will go here
    }
```

`AnnualSalary` and `DaysWorked` are integers.

Comment: Maybe your database would support XML natively, so you could just send that XML to the database and let it handle the details?

Comment: I should not use ReadXml() in DataSet. I can only use XmlDocument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  string name= xndNode ["Name"].InnerText;
  string AnnualSalary= xndNode ["AnnualSalary"].InnerText;
  string DaysWorked= xndNode ["DaysWorked"].InnerText;

 //Your sql insert command will go here;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a bit of error handling - just in case one of the nodes might not exist ...

Comment: Assuming answer as per his xml doc

Answer (score 2):

You can also use XDoc and XElement to get the element values using the LINQ way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

Answer (score 1):

xndNode contains an employee object with the Name, AnnualSalary and DaysWorked fields.  It's just a matter of converting these into an SQL statment and inserting the row into a table in your database.  The details would be database specific, but it should be something like this

```
insert into employee values (name, annual_salary, days_worked)
```

Assuming employees are keyed by name